# Xamarin.Forms - View missing menu from main page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created this menu that is working well but on some pages that are open not using the menu it is replaced with a back button. Is there anyway to make sure that menu is on all of the pages?

mainpage.xaml

```
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <pages:HomePage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

Homepage.xaml.cs

```
 var masterDetailPage = Application.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage;
        masterDetailPage.Detail = new NavigationPage((new SearchPage("A")));
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Instead of pushing your new page over your Detail page I would replace it with your new Page. `Detail = new NavigationPage((new YourPage());`

Comment: @Nick how would I do that if the MasterDetailPage.Detail is on the main page?

Comment: Assuming your app MainPage is the MasterDetail you could do `var masterDetailPage = Application.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage;`

Comment: @Nick I updated my post is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah, that should replace the current detail page with your other page and keep the menu icon. Also, keep in mind if `Application.Current.MainPage` is not a `MasterDetailPage` your `masterDetailPage` variable will be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replaced PushAsync with replacing the detail section

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new SearchPage("a"));    

var masterDetailPage = Application.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage;
masterDetailPage.Detail = new NavigationPage((new SearchPage("a")));
```